# flask upload python-base64 image

Tags: javascript, python, flask, base64

I'm trying to upload a base64 image (encoded in Python) to my webapp using Flask.
I get the encoded image but get an error when modifying the src of the image element.

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    url: getWebAppBackendUrl("return_cam"),
    data: {
        image_bytes: img_b64
    },
    success: function (filter_bytes) {
        let data = filter_bytes.heatmap
        document.getElementById("cam").src = "data:image/png;base64," + data;
    }
});
```

server side:

```
@app.route('/return_cam', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def return_cam():
    
    img_b64 = request.form.get("image_bytes") #get POST data
    api_result = client.run_function("returnCAM", image=img_b64)
    response = api_result.get("response")
    result_dict = json.loads(response)
    return json.dumps(result_dict)
```

The 'data' variable looks like this when printed in the console:

```
b'ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj/ADj...'
```

and I get ERR_INVALID_URL.

I guess there is some processing to do on this data variable...
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to decode that value.  Something like:

```
    img_b64 = request.form.get("image_bytes")
    img_b64 = img_b64.decode('utf-8')
    #...
```

Not sure if `client.run_function` will appreciate this, as it's not clear from your question what that method does.  Perhaps you could put the above mod within that function if you wrote it yourself, so that the correctly decoded value ends up within `response` as expected.

Comment: ```client.run_function``` makes an API call which returns a json object containing an image encoded using base64.b64encode() which is then converted as a string to be passed to the json object. img_b64 is the input for the API function so it shouldn't be modified

Comment: @a-clmnt Can you edit the question to show `client.run_function`.